# rviz visualization

Tags: ros, rviz, visualization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody

I have problems visualizing rviz, I have installed ros in ubuntu 10.04

In one terminal I run roscore and in another terminal I run rosrun rviz rviz and I get

rviz revision number 1.6.7
ogre_tools revision number 1.6.2
compiled against OGRE version 1.7.3 (Cthugha)
Loading general config from [/home/acp/.rviz/config]
Loading display config from [/home/acp/.rviz/display_config]
RTT Preferred Mode is PBuffer.
Texture for pass 0: creating with size 1 x 1
Segmentation fault

Any clue about this segmentation fault?

In advance thank you very much

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12061/rviz-visualization/) by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 556 on 2011-11-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

well, it is a matter of giving some tries to $ rosrun rviz rviz and rviz will be lunched

problem solved :)

---

Originally posted by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) with karma: 556 on 2011-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1